# Current mission waiting in loiter mode for a trigger

Tags: python, dronekit-python

I'm just new to DroneKit and was wondering if this kind of scenario was achievable with DroneKit run from a companion computer:

1. upload a waypoint mission in the UAV (the best for me would be that this mission is already uploaded in the UAV ... possible?)
2. have the mission wait in loiter infinite mode for a trigger message
3. send the trigger message and have the UAV continue its mission after the loiter step

Comment: Super old question but all should be achievable with DKPY.  Loading the mission from script is super easy and there are examples in the codebase already.  I do not know where you expect the trigger message to come from but it could just another .py script.   2 scripts: 1) for takeoff and loiter and wait 2) for trigger to start mission